# Best practices for watering plants with geothermal water

Tags: houseplants, watering, fertilizer

My new home uses a geothermal water system, so the sulfur levels are high (based on the lovely rotten-egg smell). I've read that sulfur can be really good for plants, but I'm wary about the amounts I'll be using, or if there are certain types of plants I should avoid using this water on.

If I need to be careful about sulfur levels, how can I measure it? (Cold water from my tap is just city water, so the warmer I make it, the higher levels of sulfur will be in the water.) Additionally, It's now spring where I'm at (Pacific Northwest), and I'm getting ready to fertilize - should I take my type of water into consideration when purchasing and using a fertilizer?

Here are some of the plants I have: Swedish Ivy, Monstera, Chinese Fan Palm, Angel-wing begonia, Spider plant, and Jade (and a large variety of other succulents).

Comment: Sulfur degradation by bacteria will acidify soils. Get yourself a PPM meter so you can tell how much you area adding. They're cheap. pH meter, also cheap, is also called for, to see where you are. They too are $10-15 American. Garden Lime will take your pH up.

Comment: The bulk of any S in geothermal water is likely sulfate . A municipality would not permit as much as 1 ppm of H2S in the water , still a strong smell. I am certain you have many other minerals which have MUCH more affect on plants than H2S. Depending on water treatment ; the H2S may be produced in the  distribution pipes by sulfate reducing bacteria( which are very common) breaking down the sulfate. I suggest finding out what is in the water before you try to adjust for it. For reference, the state of CA limited H2S in air to 0.03 ppm in 1986, I expect CA and the EPA have lower limits now.